# RegEx Substring Extraction

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a RegEx on the following text:

```
CpuUtilization\[GqIF:CA-TORONTO-1-AD-1 | FAULT-DOMAIN-3 | ocid1.image.oc1.ca-toronto-1.aaaaaaaaq4cxrudcxy5seck2cweks2zglo2tfieag6svtvqssa2zmjha | Default | ca-toronto-1 | oke-ccf3jglvbia-nc7pit2gv2a-sa65utwc32a-2 | ocid1.instance.oc1.ca-toronto-1.an2g6ljrwe6j4fqcgrlo7dmzkrtbcgr3jy35gie3qh3w65ctfh3hsd6da | VM.Standard.E2.2\]
```

I need to extract `oke-ccf3jglvbia-nc7pit2gv2a-sa65utwc32a-2` from the statement. The text above can change depending, so looking for a generic RegEx.

I tried using: `(\[^\\|\]+)\\|.+` which extract the first occurrence before `|`

Comment: Which tools language are you using? And your OS?

Comment: Is `oke` a fixed string or are these also 3 random characters? Try a capture group `\\\[[^\\]* \| \b([a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)+) \|` https://regex101.com/r/3bz2Tv/1

Comment: Give some more examples (input and expected output).

Answer (score 0):

Why use RegEx?

```js
const s = 'CpuUtilization\[GqIF:CA-TORONTO-1-AD-1 | FAULT-DOMAIN-3 | ocid1.image.oc1.ca-toronto-1.aaaaaaaaq4cxrudcxy5seck2cweks2zglo2tfieag6svtvqssa2zmjha | Default | ca-toronto-1 | oke-ccf3jglvbia-nc7pit2gv2a-sa65utwc32a-2 | ocid1.instance.oc1.ca-toronto-1.an2g6ljrwe6j4fqcgrlo7dmzkrtbcgr3jy35gie3qh3w65ctfh3hsd6da | VM.Standard.E2.2\]'

console.log(s.split(" | ")[5])
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I think your answer might be OK but the question is not clear. You don't know the programming language and you have no information how the string can be in other cases. Please keep an eye on your answer, maybe it must be changed.

Answer (score 0):

A regex solution can be

```
^(?:[^|]+ \| ){5}([^ ]+).*$
```

- `^` start of the string
- `(?:[^|]+ \| ){5}` any character but `\` followed by `|`, 5 times. (The `?:` makes this a non capturing group).
- `([^ ]+)` your string as the first group
- `.*$` any character to end of line

To get your string out of this, subtitute it with `$1` or `\1`.

Test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/). There you can test different programming languages/regex processors.

Remark:
Like the answer of Kazi this works in this case, maybe not in others.
There are no more examples in you question.
This answer is in function nearly the same.

Comment: Thanks, a million
Exactly the solution I was looking for

Comment: If so, you can accept this as answer.